# Is it possible to create a script for photoshop that changes the color of all color layers in the file to a random color?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I am trying to create a script that can change the color of all the color layers in my file to a random color and then exportt the file as a PNG.

I have already tried this code

```js
var originalRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

var activeDocument = app.activeDocument;
var colorLayers = [];

// generate a random color
var randomColor = function() {
  var color = new SolidColor();
  color.rgb.red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  color.rgb.green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  color.rgb.blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  return color;
}

// select color layers
for (var i = 0; i < activeDocument.layers.length; i++) {
  var layer = activeDocument.layers[i];
  if (layer.kind === LayerKind.COLOR || layer.kind === LayerKind.NORMAL) {
    colorLayers.push(layer);
  }
}

// change color of selected color layers
for (var i = 0; i < colorLayers.length; i++) {
  colorLayers[i].adjustColorBalance(100, 0, 0, 0);
  colorLayers[i].fill(randomColor());
}


app.preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
1320 Invalid enumeration value Line 19
if (layer.kind === LayerKind.COLOR || layer.kind === LayerKind.NORMAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

`LayerKind.COLOR` doesn't appear to be a [thing](https://theiviaxx.github.io/photoshop-docs/Photoshop/LayerKind.html).

Answer (score 0):

`return color` will just return the object. You need to return the value of the colour `color.rgb.hexValue`